# How to stop BarcodeDetector

Tags: android, google-play-services, zxing

How do I stop the barcode Scanner after scan?

**barcodeDetector**

```
    barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by stop `Runnable`? You know what a `Runnable` is ?

Comment: @ADM yeah.. Because it is going to run non stop even if i scan a QR code. I want it to go to anther activity when I scan a QR code and it stops.

Comment: Whats going to run ? `textResult.post()` this code ? This is not going to run non stop. Are you asking about stop the `Vibrator`?

Comment: @ADM the scanner still running, once I scan a QR code and it display message and it wont end after I scan and I am able to scan another. But what I want is after scan 1 QR code and it able to stop.

Comment: Which library you are using for scan ?

Comment: @ADM  'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1' 
'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'

Comment: Try calling `barcodeDetector.release();` after scanning .

Comment: @ADM where should I put it in ??

Comment: @ADM thanks. Its is working. I placed it after the dialog message show. Once again, Thank you.

Comment: @ADM Leave the post here or I should delete the post ?

Comment: Just call barcodeDetector.release(); after scannning a barcode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to release `BarcodeDetector` after scanning complete. As

```
barcodeDetector.release();
```

Comment: thanks.. But I cant vote your answer since I am having only 6 reputation. Btw thanks