# ReceiveDetections Method is Calling Multiple Times

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am scanning QR CODE but the problem is `ReceiveDetections` method is calling multiple times even after a successful scan.How can I prevent calling the api multiple times after a successful call.

here is the code snippet

```html
 public void ReceiveDetections(Detections detections)
        {
            SparseArray qrcodes = detections.DetectedItems;

            if (qrcodes.Size() != 0)
            {
                txtscankanbancloseResult.Post(async () =>
                {
                    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
                    vibrator.Vibrate(1000);

                    txtscankanbancloseResult.Text = ((Barcode)qrcodes.ValueAt(0)).RawValue;

                    try
                    {
                        var client = new HttpClient();
                        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(AppStatics.clsStatic.url + "//Kanban/SaveKanbanStatus"));

                        List<string> lstskanban = new List<string>();
                        String myDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                        string adateddate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

                        JsonScankanbanclose objjscan = new JsonScankanbanclose();

                        lstskanban.Add(txtscankanbancloseResult.Text);

                        objjscan.UpdateBy = SingletonSession.Instance().getUsername();
                        objjscan.KANBANNOList = lstskanban;
                        objjscan.IsKANBANClosed = true;

                        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objjscan);

                        var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        if (response.ReasonPhrase == "OK")
                        {
                            JArray scanresult = JArray.Parse(result);

                            Scanlist objscan = new Scanlist();

                            if (ScanSucessfull.Count == 0)
                            {
                                objscan.KanbanID = "Kanban NO";
                                objscan.KanbanQty = "Kanban Qty";

                                ScanSucessfull.Add(objscan);

                                objscan = new Scanlist();
                            }


                            // Scanlist item = ScanSucessfull.Find(c => c.KanbanID == scanresult[0]["KANBANID"].ToString());

                            //int itemPosition = ScanSucessfull.BinarySearch(scanresult[0]["KANBANID"].ToString());

                            //if (itemPosition.cou=="")
                            //{
                            objscan.KanbanID = scanresult[0]["KANBANNumber"].ToString();
                            objscan.KanbanQty = scanresult[0]["Qty"].ToString();
                            ScanSucessfull.Add(objscan);
                            //}

                            var adapter = new CustomAdapterScan(this, ScanSucessfull);

                            lstviewscankanbanclose.SetAdapter(adapter);

                            lstviewscankanbanclose.Clickable = false;
                            //lstview.Enabled = false;
                            lstviewscankanbanclose.ItemSelected += null;

                            mPlayer = Android.Media.MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.successful);
                            currentSong = Resource.Raw.successful;
                            mPlayer.SeekTo(1);
                            mPlayer.Start();
                            //Toast.MakeText(this, , ToastLength.Short).Show();
                            Helper.ShowToastMessage(this, Color.DarkGreen, "Data Save Sucessfully..", ToastLength.Short);

                            _kanbancount++;

                            txtscankanbanclosekanbancount.Text = "Kanban Count:" + " " + _kanbancount;

                            txtscankanbanclosekanbancount.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string[] result1 = result.Split(':');

                            string[] result2 = result1[1].Split('"');

                            string[] result3 = result2[1].Split('"');

                            mPlayer = Android.Media.MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.fail);
                            // mPlayer.SeekTo(2);
                            currentSong = Resource.Raw.fail;
                            mPlayer.Start();

                            //Toast.MakeText(this, result3[0].ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                            Helper.ShowToastMessage(this, Color.DarkRed, result3[0].ToString(), ToastLength.Short);

                        }
                        // dialog.Hide();
                        cameraSource.Start(surfaceView.Holder);
                        //txtResult.Text = "";
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        Helper.ShowToastMessage(this, Color.DarkRed, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short);
                        //Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        // txtResult.Text = "";
                        txtscankanbancloseResult.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                        //cameraSource.Start(surfaceView.Holder);
                    }

                });


                using (var h = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper))
                    h.Post(() =>
                    {
                        cameraSource.Stop();
                        // Toast.MakeText(this, "This Kanban Already Scanned....", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    });


            }
        }
```

Here is the code where I crate and open the camera source to scan the QR code

```html
 private void btnkanbanscan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                #region validation

                if (spnSiteID.SelectedItemPosition < 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Please Select Site...");
                }
                if (spnLocation.SelectedItemPosition < 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Please Select Location..");
                }
                if (spnInspactionType.SelectedItemPosition < 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Please Select Inspection Type..");
                }
                #endregion


                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
                View scanview = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.scan_popup, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialogBuilder.SetView(scanview);

                surfaceView = scanview.FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.spvscan);
                dialog = alertDialogBuilder.Create();
                dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                dialog.Show();

                barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                    .SetBarcodeFormats(BarcodeFormat.Code128 | BarcodeFormat.QrCode)
                    .Build();

                cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                    .SetRequestedPreviewSize(480, 480)
                    .SetAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .Build();

                surfaceView.Holder.AddCallback(this);
                barcodeDetector.SetProcessor(this);


                surfaceView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

                _definemethod = "KANBAN";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helper.ShowToastMessage(this, Color.DarkRed, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short);

                //Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
```

NCTB: I noticed that after opening the dialog to scan the QR CODE the `ReceiveDetections` method get called frequently and the scanned value comes in `detections` parameter .which is normal and it supposed to do so.But the problem is after a successful scan it should not call anymore.

Comment: if the problem is that ReceiveDetections is being called multiple times, it is unlikely the problem is in ReceiveDetections itself.  Where is the code that actually performs the scan?

Comment: Thanks @jason.I've added some extra information.please have a look.
Any kind of help is highly appropriated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140928/how-to-stop-barcodedetector